# Thymeleaf templating with multiple files

Tags: templates, layout, thymeleaf

I have the following question/problem:

I want to "build" a templating system where I can aggregte the page to be shown from a couple of different `*.html` files. For example I have a layout.html with basic page structure and I want to fill it with content from `header.html`, `content.html` and `footer.html`.

I tried it using the Thymeleaf fragment mechanism but that always failed when it comes to aggregate the head definitions (css, js) from the different input files.

I Also tried the Thymeleaf layout dialect mechanism that aggregates the head definitions correctly but it seems only capable of working with one layout and one content file using the `layout:decorate` directive. Am I right?

The following code snippets are simple and straighforward ... I just want to include `header.html`, `column1.html`, `column2.html` and `footer.html` into `layout.html` as described above. Problem is that I only can include the according content sections using ThymeLeafs replace/fragment mechanism. But how can I process the `head` and `script` sections to include them into the layout?

**layout.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Thyme Fiddling</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/styles/main.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/styles/layout.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js}"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="layout">

        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <div th:replace="~{header :: content}">placeholder for header</div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentWrapper">

            <div id="column1Wrapper">
                <div th:replace="~{column1 :: content}">placeholder for column1</div>
            </div>

            <div id="column2Wrapper">
                <div th:replace="~{column2 :: content}">placeholder for column2</div>
            </div>

        </div>    

        <div id="footerWrapper">
            <div th:replace="~{footer :: content}">placeholder for footer</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**header.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/styles/header.css}"/>
</head>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>                        

<div th:fragment="content">                  
    <div class="center">Header !!!</div>
</div>
```

**column1.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/styles/column1.css}"/>
</head>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>                        

<div th:fragment="content">                  
    <div class="center">Column1 !!!</div>
</div>
```

**column2.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/styles/column2.css}"/>
</head>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>                        

<div th:fragment="content">                  
    <div class="center">Column2 !!!</div>
</div>
```

**footer.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/styles/footer.css}"/>
</head>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>                        

<div th:fragment="content">                  
    <div class="center">Footer !!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just added some explaining snippets ... hope this helps to understand my problem ;-)

Comment: I'm really frustrated there's no answer to this because I have the same question.  I don't think this is possible, but I'd love to be proven wrong because I want to do something very similar.

Comment: Sad but true ... Finally i switched back to Tiles/JSP ... Not the technology I wanted to use but definitely workling ...